# How to use svg imported from React Component with use-image in konva?

Tags: reactjs, svg, konva

How to use svg imported from React Component with [use-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-image) in [konva](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Intro.html)?

I try import svg from Component but it's not working any way and it's not return any error.
Same svg code imported from .svg file works good but i want to pass props to show in svg so i have to do this in this way. :)

Stamp.js

```
const Stamp = () => {
    return (
        <svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="120" height="120" />
        </svg>
    );
};

export default Stamp;
```

Canvas.js

```
import useImage from 'use-image';
import Stamp from 'components/Stamp';

const Canvas = () => {
    const PlaceStamp = () => {
        const [image] = useImage(Stamp);
        return <Image image={image} x={position.x} y={position.y} />;
    };

    return (
        <Stage
            width={width}
            height={height}
            ref={konvaRef}
            onClick={() => {
                handleClick();
                IsDirty(true);
            }}
            onTap={() => {
                handleClick();
                IsDirty(true);
            }}>
            <Layer>
                {dirty && <PlaceStamp />}
            </Layer>
        </Stage>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the exact same thing.
(And thanks for the opportunity to register an account on stack-overflow,haha)

I know this isn't a direct solution.
You may have already looked into the following
[this](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/DOM_Portal.html).

I imported the  from 'react-konva-utils' and embedded the  as described in this official documentation and it worked.

```
<Html>
　　<XCircleIconGray />
</Html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It think your code is correct. You should just add `width` and `height` properties on your `Image` tag to show the image on canvas, like this:

```
const PlaceStamp = () => {
    const [image] = useImage(Stamp);
    return <Image image={image} x={position.x} y={position.y} width={100} height={100}/>;
};
```